# Sort Multiple language data in SQL Server by collation (Why my query does not work)

Tags: sql-server, sorting, collation, hindi

I have a table column which have multiple language data.

I need to sort according to my specified language like Hindi.

How to achieve it though collation or something else?

- Column name: `Comments`
- Type : `Nvarchar(MAx)`

Sample column data

```
    This is an example
    To je příklad.
    هذا مثال على ذلك.
    उदाहरण है.
    यह एक उदाहरण है.
    ಈ ಒಂದು ಉದಾಹರಣೆಯಾಗಿದೆ.
```

Output after 'Hindi' sorting should be :

```
उदाहरण है.
यह एक उदाहरण है.
This is an example
To je příklad.
هذا مثال على ذلك.
ಈ ಒಂದು ಉದಾಹರಣೆಯಾಗಿದೆ.
```

Script used:

```html
CREATE TABLE dbo.Data
( unicodeData NVARCHAR(200)
)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Data ( unicodeData)
VALUES
 ( N'This is an example')
, (N'यह एक उदाहरण है.')
, (N'उदाहरण है.')
, (N'ಈ ಒಂದು ಉದಾಹರಣೆಯಾಗಿದೆ.')
, (N'एक उदाहरण है.')
, (N'هذا مثال على ذلك.')
, (N'To je příklad.');
GO

select * from dbo.unicodeData
order by unicodedata Collate Indic_General_100_CI_AI
```

Comment: which database? sql server,oracle?

Comment: Sql Server 2008 R2/ 2012

Answer (score 0):

Use [Order by Column COLLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) syntax. Need to use [Indic_General_90_CI_AS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a836c6b1-34f5-4e26-88b5-5b4aa0c38316/i-want-to-use-hindi-collation-for-one-of-my-database-not-server?forum=sqldatabaseengine) collation. Since it seems that

> The reference says that Hindi (deprecated in this(2005) release)
>   discontinued and replaced by Indic_General_90_CI_AS (Unicode only).

```
SELECT Comments from TABLEX
ORDER BY Comments 
COLLATE Indic_General_90_CI_AS ASC;
```

Collation and sort normally used one language only. You want multiple language sorting, you need to add custom values to your data. I added languageSortingPriority column to your table, then used languageSortingPriority column for your sorting.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.unicodeData
( 
  languageUsed VARCHAR(50)
  ,languageSortingPriority int
, unicodeData NVARCHAR(200)
, nonUnicodeData VARCHAR(200) -- same data in a normal VARCHAR column for comparison
, comments VARCHAR(100)
)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.unicodeData (languageUsed, languageSortingPriority,unicodeData, nonUnicodeData, comments)
VALUES
 ('English', 2, N'This is an example', N'This is an example', NULL)
, ('Hindi', 1,N'यह एक उदाहरण है.', N'यह एक उदाहरण है.', 'Using the preceding N in both strings but VARCHAR is still a ?')
, ('Hindi', 1, N'यह एक उदाहरण है.', 'यह एक उदाहरण है.', 'Not using the preceding N in both strings so both are a ?')
, ('Kannada' ,3, N'ಈ ಒಂದು ಉದಾಹರಣೆಯಾಗಿದೆ.', N'ಈ ಒಂದು ಉದಾಹರಣೆಯಾಗಿದೆ.', NULL)
, ('Arabic', 3,N'هذا مثال على ذلك.', N'هذا مثال على ذلك.', NULL)
, ('Czech', 2 ,N'To je příklad.', N'To je příklad.', NULL);
GO

select * from dbo.unicodeData
order by languageSortingPriority,unicodedata Collate Indic_General_100_CI_AI DESC
```

See [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c063/1/0) here.

Comment: Hi Atilla,Thanks for your quick response, but your given query is not giving needed output  mentioned in my comment. I have used following script but no success.

Comment: @Shashank this is built-in solution. If you need something special, you should update your question to give more information? For example you can add "Why my query does not work?"

Comment: Hi Atilla,Thanks for your reply, can you please explain your statement  more that is "Collation and sort normally used one language only".<br>Can you describe that how collation work in order by for any specific language ( hindi  in my case) in detail for a column that have multiple language data.

Comment: Good day Atilla Ozgur,
Using one specific collate in order to sort multiple languages data will leads to bad order for all other languages. For example using Atilla's answer which use specific collate Indic_General_100_CI_AI do not fit for all languages that the user use.

Answer (score 0):

Good day, I have already answered the OP question at MSDN forums. basically you need to sort by each one of the collations.

you can see the original thread here, with the answer:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ccc1d16f-926f-46c8-8579-b2eecf661e7c/sort-miultiple-language-data-in-sql-serevr-by-collation?forum=transactsql

You can see an article on this issue on TechNet here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31194.t-sql-sort-data-by-multiple-languages.aspx

**I hope this useful :-)**